# How to get comparable attributes on the up-sell page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I succeeded to got all the comparable attributes by the following code:

```
$_attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$_attributes->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.is_comparable', array('1'));
```

But I can't call these attributes from the up-sell products when I'm trying:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_link, $this->getProductAttributeValue($_link, $_attribute), $_attribute->getAttributeCode()) ?>
```

Comment: No? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but that could work for you:

```
<?php $_attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection'); ?>
<?php $_attributes->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.is_comparable', array('1')); ?>
<?php $attributeCodes = array(); ?>
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <?php $attributeCodes[] = $_attribute->getData('attribute_code'); ?>
<?php enforeach; ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($this->getItemCollection()->getItems() as $_link): ?>
    <li>
        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?></a></h3>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($attributeCodes as $attributeCode): ?>
                <li>
                    <?php echo ($_link->getData($attributeCode)); ?>
                </li>
            <?php enforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <!-- ... -->
    </li>
<?php enforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

-- where `$attributeCodes` will hold an array of comparable attribute codes which you then can re-use inside the upsell-item's foreach. However, you should really overthink whether you want to put a `foreach` inside another since this may have some noticeable performance impact on larger upsell-lists and many comparable attributes...

Comment: I'm trying to show comparable attributes in the up-sell block on the product page.

Comment: I changed my code to: `<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_link, $_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_link), $_attribute->getAttributeCode()); echo $_attribute->getAttributeCode(); ?>` And now the attributes are shown but only ones with "Used in Product Listing" activated.

Comment: @Demi_Cogni You may post a bit bigger snippet as an answer if that was what solved it for you

Answer (score 2):

My solution

```
    <?php $_attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$_attributes->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.is_comparable', array('1')); ?>
<?php if ($_link = $this->getIterableItem()): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"
           class="product-image"><img
                    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(125) ?>"
                    width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"/></a>
        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>"
                                    title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?></a>
        </h3>
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true, '-upsell') ?>
        <div class="std">
            <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
                <div>
                    <span class="std"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_link, $_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_link), $_attribute->getAttributeCode());
                        echo $_attribute->getAttributeCode(); ?></span></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php else: ?>
    <li class="empty"></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And set "Used in Product Listing" to Yes in Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes